# Help on GARCH-X model theory

Tags: variance, heteroscedasticity, garch, predictor

I need to understand how a GARCH-X model (GARCH with explanatory variable) works.
What I've understood so far is:
we have a simple GARCH(1,1) model:  [image: garch(1,1)]

If I add to the conditional variance equation an explanatory variable (i.e an index that captures the change in people concerns about climate change) the only thing that change is that my variable replaces the $\alpha_0$ in the GARCH equation above?

Answer (score 0):

The explanatory variable $x$ does not replace $\alpha_0$, it comes as an additional term:
$$
\sigma_t^2=\alpha_0+\alpha_1 u_{t-1}^2+\beta_1\sigma_{t-1}^2+\gamma x.
$$
Also note that the formulas you have included in your post are for GARCH(p,q), not GARCH(1,1).

Comment: So, if the coefficient of X results significant, we can say that X affects volatility, right?

Comment: @TF7, well, correlation does not imply causation, but you at least have a statistical/probabilistic relationship (though as usual, under a 95% confidence level there is a 5% chance the finding is spurious). It may or may not be causal.

Comment: So, is there anything that I can add to the theory of GARCH to explain the GARCH-X model? For example, what the coefficient of X means, or I should only report the equation for the GARCH-X and the rest remains the same as the classic GARCH?

Comment: @TF7, if you know how to interpret the results of a linear regression, then this is not much different. Only in GARCH you have an equation for the conditional variance, while in linear regression you have an equation for the conditional mean (plus a random error term).